# What makes a Layout render in Marionette.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Consider the following JS:

```
var ChildLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: "... let's not go here ...",
  initialize: function() {
    console.log('Child Layout Initialized'); // registers once
  },
  onRender: function() {
    console.log('Rendered'); // registers 2 times
  },
});

var ParentLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: "<div class='child-region'></div>",
  regions: { childRegion: '.child-region' },
  onRender: function() {
    console.log('About to initialize ChildLayout'); // registers once
    this.childRegion.show(new ChildLayout());
  },
});
```

In the above, I use the `ParentLayout` to render the `ChildLayout` in one of its `Regions`. Notice that I do not pass any sort of model to the `ChildLayout`.

The `show` function, a property of Marionette, should logically initialize and then render the model once. A Marionette `View` should not re-render itself unless there is some change in its model, from what I understand.

In my application, the `onRender` of `ChildLayout` is triggering in my code several times, though its `initialize` only triggers once.

I cannot see what is causing Marionette to render the `ChildLayout` multiple times - this does not make sense.

Any insight?

### edit

On inspecting [the source code of Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette), the `show` function clearly only renders the passed view once, right after initializing. So the re-renders could only occur from the Layout deciding autonomously to re-render. Interesting.

Comment: Hm, very strange - i've built fiddle and dont see any duplications on render - http://jsfiddle.net/J9mVL/. Have following output : 'About to initialize ChildLayout',  'Child Layout Initialized', 'Rendered'

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code above either. At first glance you might guess that the parent get's rerendered and thus rerendering the child, however it's stated that that's only registered once. Did you try not using a layout as childview but just a simple ItemView for example?

Comment: @WilbertvandeRidder I didn't try that because, as you can see I wrote 'let's not go here' in the Child's template, it is a very large layout that itself has sub-regions.

Comment: While that's probably true, you could test it using a simple template and an Itemview to see if the problem persists. If not, you have reason to look at your template/child views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be my own problem with a Zombie View, which I since handled.